# Which Sigma SA Mount lenses render corner to corner sharp images on APS-H format of the Sigma sd Quattro H?

Tags: sigma, aps-c, foveon

Sigma's sd Quattro is an APS-C format camera, while the sd Quattro H with the same mount is an APS-H format camera with a larger sensor than APS-C. Compared to "full frame", APS-C has a crop factor of ~1.6 and APS-H has a crop factor of ~1.3.

Sigma's SA mount lenses are either APS-C lenses and some of their lenses are full frame lenses. Is there a list of modern SA mount lenses that work well on the sd Quattro H with great corner to corner sharpness? For example, will the two APS-C f1.8 Art zoom lenses that Sigma released for the sd Quattro render sharp images corner to corner with the larger image circle required for APS-H?

Thank you.

Comment: Define "sharp". It can vary greatly depending on display size, viewing distance, visual acuity of the viewer, etc. If you're pixel peeping, no lens will be as "sharp" on the edges and in the corners as in the center when the lens is properly focused on whatever is in the center of the frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigma's DG lenses, which project full-frame–sized image circles, won't vignette on the sd Quattro H. To my knowledge, nobody has compiled a list of every Sigma DC lens for the purpose of describing how much each lens will vignette; it's safe to assume that every DC lens will vignette on the sd H to some degree or another, simply because those lenses are designed to project an image circle sufficient for 1.5-crop APS-C sensors, not 1.3 APS-H.

Some example discussions or resources/images regarding DC lenses on the sd H:

- [SD Quattro H with 17-50mm f2.8 EX OS DC](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/4300862) at DPReview.com, from July 2018. There is noticeable vignetting wide-open, but even at f/6.3, the vignetting is unacceptable IMO.
- [Lens Options for SD Quattro H (also ? about adapted M42 Lenses)](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/4513887) at DPReview.com, from August 2020. No photos from the Sigma lenses, but discussion is that the 17–50 f/2.8 and Art 18-35/1.8 all vignette through most of the aperture and zoom range.